# Reshape Pandas dataframe that contains all years in one column and months separated across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataframe that contains sales per product for different time periods over different years:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product': {0: '1', 1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '2'},
                   'Year': {0: 2000, 1: 2001, 2: 2001, 3:2002},
                   'Jan-Feb': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 2, 3:4},
                    'Mar-Apr': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3:6}})
```

`df` has products the sales of products 1 and 2 for each `year` but the periods of time within a year are presented in different columns. In this example I present two columns but there are four more representing the remaining periods of two consecutive months within a year.

I would like to reshape `df` to look like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Product': {0: '1', 1: '1', 2: '1', 3: '1', 4: '2', 5: '2', 6: '2', 7: '2'},
                   'Year': {0: 2000, 1: 2000, 2: 2001, 3:2001,4: 2001, 5: 2001, 6: 2002, 7:2002},
                   'Period': {0: 'Jan-Feb', 1: 'Mar-Apr', 2: 'Jan-Feb', 3:'Mar-Apr', 4: 'Jan-Feb', 5: 'Mar-Apr', 6: 'Jan-Feb', 7:'Mar-Apr'},
                   'Sales': {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 4, 7: 6}})
```

In this case, month periods are all in one column and sales in a different column. I have tried different forms of reshaping but I'm clearly missing something as I haven't been successful in finding one that does what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `melt`

```
out = df.melt(['Product','Year'], var_name = 'Period', value_name = 'Sales')
  Product  Year   Period  Sales
0       1  2000  Jan-Feb      2
1       1  2001  Jan-Feb      4
2       2  2001  Jan-Feb      2
3       2  2002  Jan-Feb      4
4       1  2000  Mar-Apr      1
5       1  2001  Mar-Apr      2
6       2  2001  Mar-Apr      1
7       2  2002  Mar-Apr      6
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `stack()`:

```
df = df.set_index(['Product','Year']).stack(0).reset_index()
df.columns = ['Product','Year','Period','Sales']
```

**Output**:

```
  Product  Year   Period  Sales
0       1  2000  Jan-Feb      2
1       1  2000  Mar-Apr      1
2       1  2001  Jan-Feb      4
3       1  2001  Mar-Apr      2
4       2  2001  Jan-Feb      2
5       2  2001  Mar-Apr      1
6       2  2002  Jan-Feb      4
7       2  2002  Mar-Apr      6
```